# Making a matrix in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, matrix, random, wolfram-mathematica

I am currently working with mathematica and I got stuck on some technicalities.

```
Rvec[R_] := UnitVector[Length[R], RandomInteger[{1, Length[R]}]]
Fvec[R_] := R - Rvec[R] + Rvec[R]
vec[R_] := Module[{S = Fvec[R]}, If[Count[S, -1] > 0, R, S]]
Loop[R_, n_] := For[i = 1; L = R, i < n + 1, i++, L = vec[L]; Print[L]]
```

The idea is that I now have a loop going that will randomly subtract one number from one entry in a set and add it to another in the next iteration, but with the catch that no entry can drop below zero. The output I then get is a set of outcomes put beneath each other.

Having done that I would like to know how I could put the entire output in the form of one matrix:

[https://i.gyazo.com/a4ef70ba5670fd53003e0ac5ec1e434e.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35QPS.png)

Instead of having the output like that, I would like to have it in matrix form, as in having this set of outputs placed in a larger set containing those sets as elements. This would greatly help me, as I would be able to manipulate and work with the entire output.

Comment: Instead of `For`, I suggest `Nest`.  For collecting results in a procedural loop, look up `Sow`/`Reap`. If you're a beginner, [I suggest you forget about the `For` loop for a while](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12). Finally, try to avoid names starting with capitals, as you are risking conflicts with built-in or package symbols.

Comment: I meant `NestList` actually, not `Nest`.

Comment: maybe I've missed something but why not just make the `For` loop a `Table` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make matrix by consequently adding vector by vector, you can do like this:

```
vector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
matrix = {};   (* Initialize matrix *)
Do[matrix = Append[matrix, vector], 5];   (* Construct matrix by adding line by line*)
MatrixForm[matrix]   (* Print matrix *)
```

Please tell me If I didn't understanf youy problem properly.